# How can I fit my graphs in my computer screen

Tags: r, plot, size, legend

Since a week I'm following a course with which we have to use R and RStudio. In class we had to make plots, put I think my computer screen is too small or something because all my plots come out way to big and also my legends are all over my plot. Already tried a lot (like changing the cex) but still won't work...
See examples:
[plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HeXl.png)[plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZydu.png)

Comment: Click `Zoom` and it will open a window which you can resize. You can also resize the pane by dragging your mouse on the edge of the pane.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `windows(10,10)` before plotting. A new plotting window appears.

You can control the window dimensions by changing the numbers in the call, the first number refers to the width and second to the height.